# Using YOLO in OpenCV shows wrong detections at the top edge of the image

Tags: android, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have trained a yolo-tiny model on my own dataset. The model works great in Python with OpenCV. But when I want to run the same model in OpenCV (3.4.3) on an Android Smartphone, I get false detections on the top edge of the frame. I am using the [dnn tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d0/d6c/tutorial_dnn_android.html) from OpenCV.

The net is created like:

```java
// Net net = Dnn.readNet(getPath("my_yolov3-tiny.weights", this), getPath("my_yolov3-tiny.cfg", this));
Net net = Dnn.readNetFromDarknet(getPath("my_yolov3-tiny.cfg", this), getPath("my_yolov3-tiny.weights", this));
```

The result is the same on both methods.

I am logging the detection to Logcat with the following code:

```java
Log.e(TAG, "detection 0th object: classID=" + classId + " - label: " + label + " - xleft: " + xLeftBottom + " - yLeft: " + yLeftBottom + " - xright: " + xRightTop + " - yright: " + yRightTop);
```

and get the following output:

```
classID=0 - label: [my_object_name]: 0.24151088297367096 - xleft: 43 - yLeft: 0 - xright: 0 - yright: 0
```

I get detections, even though the frame is black. Is there any known problem in this version?

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, the information you provide is not enough for us to help find the bug.

If you enter a black screen on noraml ubuntu PC with your transfer learned model, does it returns false as well? If yes, model problem. If no, go next line

If your transfer learned model works on both opencv and python, then there shouldn`t be issue running in android. It seems you have a bug or sth. Post all or the key part where you think you might make a mistake.

If you want to run it in android urgently to finish a school project, you can follow this post in getting it done. Just switch the model to yours.

https://github.com/ishay2b/android-yolo